# Send message programmatically with converse.js?

Tags: javascript, api, xmpp, converse.js

I am using converse.js to provide chat functionality.
I am looking for a way to send some messages thru the API based on other buttons in the rest of the system.

```
var chat = converse.chats.open(jid);
chat.open();
chat.sendMessage(message);
```

chat.sendMessage() fails because the chatbox that has been returned only has limited functionality.
https://conversejs.org/docs/html/development.html#the-chats-grouping

Should I override the wrappedChatBox functionality or is there a cleaner way to send a message?
https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js/blob/0746f2aa682b3a03a5c04a94570352e6921cde86/src/converse-core.js#L273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bit more lower-level than you'd like, but you can send message stanzas via `converse.send(stanza);`

So, to send a chat message:

```
var msg = converse.env.$msg({
     from: 'juliet@example.com/balcony',
     to:'romeo@example.net',
     type:'chat'
});
converse.send(msg);
```

That said, I think the wrapper can be extended to add a `send` method there as well (check in next release).

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old question but it seems that the answer has changed so I just wanted to comment here for those who come along in the future.  I am writing a converse headless app and I had to use [_converse.api.send()](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/api/-_converse.api.html)

The _converse object is accessed by creating a [plugin](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/plugin_development.html).